# Two equivalent functions have two different outputs

Tags: r, message, cat

The following two first functions find all NAs in a vector `x` and replace it with `y`

Now the first function:

```
f <- function(x, y) {
    is_miss <- is.na(x)
    x[is_miss] <- y
    message(sum(is_miss), " missings replaced by the value ", y)
    x
}
x<-c(1,2,NA,4,5)
# Call f() with the arguments x = x and y = 10
f(x=x,y=10)

#result is
1 missings replaced by the value 10
[1]1 2 10 4 5
```

The second function:

```
 f <- function(x, y) {
    is_miss <- is.na(x)
    x[is_miss] <- y
    cat(sum(is.na(x)), y, "\n")
    x
 }
x<-c(1,2,NA,4,5)
# Call f() with the arguments x = x and y = 10
f(x=x,y=10)

#result is
0 10
[1]1 2 10 4 5
```

The only difference between the two functions is the message/cat line in each function. Why the first function prints **1** missings replaced by the value **10** but the second prints **0 10** instead of **1 10** (they all mean 1 NA in the vector replaced by value 10).

Comment: Where is the `x` vector?

Comment: They are NOT equivalent: in the first function you use `sum(is_miss)` while in the second you use `sum(is.na(x))` after changing `x` in the previous line.

Comment: Just ran the two functions and they both throw the same error. hinted by @RichScriven: `Error in f(x = x, y = 10) : object 'x' not found`. So I've changed `is.na` to `missing` and the error changed but the functions still don't work. The error became `Error in x[is_miss] <- y : object 'x' not found`.

Comment: @RichScriven My bad. x<-c(1,2,NA,4,5)

Comment: @RuiBarradas  I changed the second function to be 'sum(is_miss)' and the results are the same. So that must be the problem.  But isn't  'is_miss = is.na(x)' ? Why they produce different results?

Comment: No they are not the same, just read my very first comment: you have changed `x` after `is_miss = is.na(x)`. Also, do you have an object named `x` in your globalenv? What is the result of `grep("x", ls())`? (BTW, place code between back quotes not normal ones.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second function `x[is_miss] <- y` replaces the NAs. When you recheck their count in `cat(sum(is.na(x)), y, "\n")`, it will be different than before the previous statement. Try replacing `cat(sum(is.na(x)), y, "\n")` in second function with `cat(sum(is_miss), y, "\n")`.

Comment: But ' is_miss <- is.na(x) ', I assume they are exactly the same. Why do they have different outcomes?

Comment: I tried `sum(is_miss)` and `sum(is.na(x))` and they both print `1`. I still think they are the same thing.

Comment: The `<-` operator denotes assignment, not binding. If you assign `is.na(x)` to `is_miss` and then change `x`, `is_miss` won't recalculate automatically. This is what happened in your 2nd function. First, you store (copy) the NA-ness vector of `x` to `is_miss`. Then you replace NAs of `x` with replicated `y`, turning NAs into regular values. At that point the values of `is.na(x)` and `is_miss` will differ if there had been any NAs in `x`, as then all of them have been replaced. `is_miss` will not reflect that, unless you do `is_miss <- is.na(x)` again after the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Eva, you are not seeing this right. In the code below I will, hopefully, make things clear by showing 3 different versions of your functions. I have named them `f`, `g` and `h`.

```
#The first function
f <- function(x, y) {
    is_miss <- is.na(x)
    x[is_miss] <- y
    message(sum(is_miss), " missings replaced by the value ", y)
    x
}
x<-c(1,2,NA,4,5)
# Call f() with the arguments x = x and y = 10
f(x=x,y=10)

#result is
1 missings replaced by the value 10
[1]  1  2 10  4  5

#The second function:
g <- function(x, y) {
    is_miss <- is.na(x)
    x[is_miss] <- y
    cat(sum(is.na(x)), y, "\n")
    x
}
x<-c(1,2,NA,4,5)
# Call g() with the arguments x = x and y = 10
g(x=x,y=10)
0 10 
[1]  1  2 10  4  5

#The third function:
h <- function(x, y) {
    is_miss <- is.na(x)
    x[is_miss] <- y
    cat(sum(is_miss), y, "\n")  # ONLY DIFFERENCE FROM 'g'
    x
}
x<-c(1,2,NA,4,5)
# Call h() with the arguments x = x and y = 10
h(x=x,y=10)
1 10 
[1]  1  2 10  4  5
```